# Why docker image build throws /usr/bin/env: ‘sh\r’: No such file or directory?

Tags: docker, gradlew

Building docker image.......
**/usr/bin/env: ‘sh\r’: No such file or directory**
execution failed

**complete script**

```
#!/bin/bash
 echo "Building docker image......."
. gradle.properties
 IMAGE="$dockerRegistry/$1"
 IMAGE_TAG="$releaseVersion-$(git log -1 --pretty=%h)"
 if ./gradlew clean :$1:jibDockerBuild -x test; then
 echo "Pushing docker image...."
 docker tag $IMAGE $IMAGE:$IMAGE_TAG
 docker push $IMAGE:$IMAGE_TAG
 else
 echo "execution failed"
 exit 1
  fi
 exit 0
```

Comment: Can you also post your Dockerfile here?

Comment: `$'\r'` is the carriage return. Your code is presumably saved as a DOS/Windows text file, not a UNIX one. DOS text files separate lines with a `CRLF` sequence (`$'\r\n'`), whereas UNIX text files *end* lines (including the last one) with a linefeed alone (`$'\n'`).

Comment: See the very first entry in the "Before asking about problematic code" section of https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are shell scripts sensitive to encoding and line endings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39527571/are-shell-scripts-sensitive-to-encoding-and-line-endings)

Comment: That said, it's a different program that's throwing your error, not this one. This code isn't using `env` *or* `sh`. Maybe it's your copy of `gradlew` that's checked in that way? Either way, whichever program it is, the bug is as described above.

Comment: Add printing commands at the top of your script `set -x`  to narrow down which command exactly fails your script.

Answer (score 8):

Try to adjust your file endings for gradlew file:

```
   dos2unix .\gradlew
```

Comment: shouldn't it be: `dos2unix ./gradlew`?

Comment: Maybe backslash is about Windows. You can try according to your operating system.